# How to save form data to local MongoDB with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

can anyone add the scripts  to save data gotten from html form  to a local mongoDB.i tried man  ways but  always got errors(db is not a function ,client is no defined, etc ) please help me

Comment: if you tried anything please share your code and use specific errors/problems so that we can solve that

Comment: Show us what you've done

Comment: Don't worry. One step at a time. Post your code, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From your problem, to get data from html form, you can use body-parser package or express inbuilt middleware.
You can access the data from form in the backend by doing req.body.
You have to give a name attribute to every input
like

`<input type="text" name="username">`

and access it using req.body.name.

Rest is up to you.

Comment: i changed but same again .i  think i have a problem with db name, which is right ? var db=client.db("mydb") or = mongoclient.db("mydb ") or =db.db("mydb") ?

Comment: Looking the code, client is undefined because  there is no client defined

Comment: yes actually i changed some and forget to change it as well .my problem is how to get db

Comment: db.collection("xxx"),insertOne({xxxxx}) in this syntax where do we define db how do we call it ?

Comment: in the db.insertOne(post) can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const express=require("express");
const app =express();
const mongoose =require("mongoose")
const bodyParser =require("body-parser")
const route =require("./route")

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('./htmls')) 

const dbConnection= mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb",
   { useNewUrlParser:true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true },
   ()=> {console.log("connected to  DB");})

app.post("/user",(req,res)=>{
    dbConnection.then((db)=>{
         var post={name:req.body.name,
                   surname:req.body.lastname}
        var db=client.db("mydb")
        db.collection("myDataCol").insertOne({post})
        client.close();  });})

module.exports=app
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>form</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h2>New User</h2>
        <hr/>

        <form action="/user" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="text" name="lastName">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <hr>

        <form action="/user/delete" method="POST">
             <input type="text" name="name" >
            <input type="text" name="lastName">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: these are my codes ,sorry for that mess ,this site is so confusing i can not answer the demands from the site i want add codes i cant ,i want to edit i cant what a hell